# Duplicates while using multiple join in select query

Tags: postgresql, select, join, left-join

I am currently trying to query the psql database. And there are three tables involved in the query and their structure looks like below

Product Table

```
   Productid    Name    Quantity    DateCreated
```

Sample Table

```
    Sampleid    Name    DateReceived    Productid   Descriptionid
```

Description Table

```
   Descriptionid    Description
```

So when I am using the query like below

```
  Select p.Name,p.Quantity,s.DateReceived,d.Description
     from public.Product p
     left join Sample s on s.Productid = p.Productid
     left join Description d on s.Descriptionid = d.Descriptionid
```

This returns data but with many duplicates in it.

```
 Project Name   Quantity    DateReceived    Description
 13CD             1.00      7/12/2013 0:00    ABCD
 13CD             1.00      7/12/2013 0:00    ABCD
 13CD             1.00      7/12/2013 0:00    ABCD
 13CD             1.00      7/12/2013 0:00    ABCD
 13FML            4.00      8/7/2013 0:00     EFGH
 13FML            4.00      8/7/2013 0:00     EFGH
 13CD             4.00      7/12/2013 0:00    IJKL
 13CD             4.00      7/12/2013 0:00    IJKL
```

I am new to join and not sure if I need to change the joins

Comment: Can you show us what you got from the above query and what you expect?

Comment: You could simply add a distinct after select to remove all duplicate rows, be wary that this can misrepresent data depending on the use

Comment: @GurV I have updated my question with the result

Comment: @user4912134 - Post the data from input tables as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
GROUP BY d.Descriptionid
```

or some other unique identifier to the actual order and not the product and you should receive what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting all transactions so there are multiple rows because of similar transactions

doing something to the affect of

```
Select p.Name,sum(p.Quantity) as Quantity,s.DateReceived,d.Description
     from public.Product p
     left join Sample s on s.Productid = p.Productid
     left join Description d on s.Descriptionid = d.Descriptionid
group by
 p.Name,s.DateReceived,d.Description
```

should display what you are looking for and quantity will be the number of transactions

or if you're looking for just the information from the rows and the count doesn't nessesary matter, just doing

```
select distinct ...
```

should do the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

You `Product` and `Sample` tables have duplicate attributes named `Name`, requiring one to be renamed (did you mean `ProductName` rather than `ProjectName`?). Your expected results (no nulls) suggest you don't actually need outer joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProjectName, Quantity, DateReceived, Description
  FROM Sample
       NATURAL JOIN
       Description
       NATURAL JOIN
       ( SELECT Name AS ProjectName, Productid, Quantity
           FROM Product ) t;
```